# I'm Unable to create new folder and paste anything in my 2nd and 3rd partition

Tags: partitioning, permissions, root, disk, disk-usage

I want to use 2nd (`/dev/sda5`) and 3rd  (`/dev/sda6`) drive for my personal use but I can't do it. And I have no space. I have left 1st partition(140gb) for system and I want to use 2nd(40gb) and 3rd(50gb). Help me what should I do?

[image]

### First `/dev/sda5` Properties

[image]

### First `/dev/sda5` Permissions

[image]

### Second `/dev/sda6` Properties

[image]

### Second `/dev/sda6` Permissions

[image]

I am even ready to reinstall Os. Tell me what I should do now to prevent this issue?

```
cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=6a2c6bb2-3f79-4598-b24d-52743c552a8f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=1572-BBA5  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=e9d72749-3544-42df-9529-b45783fbd37b none            swap    sw
```

Comment: You are not the owner of the drives. Change ownership of the drives to your username with `sudo chown -R username:username /mnt/karmoksh`.

Comment: @user68186 I did a few things and now I am able to do it. I want to ask that is it okay to use the 2nd and 3rd partition for personal usage. because I read some that it is not safe.

Comment: @user68186 I did a few things and now I am able to do it. I want to ask that is it okay to use the 2nd and 3rd partition for personal usage. because I read some that it is not safe.

Comment: Yes it is safe, why the jfs one though ?  It is very common to use independent partitions for /home and for /opt but as scratch or arbitrary storage they should be fine.

Comment: If you fixed the problem then please write to own answer in the "Your Answer" window below. Then accept your answer as correct. This will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://netgator.blogspot.com/2011/07/can-not-create-file-folder-on-newly.html
This worked out for me.
Use the cmd in terminal

```
sudo chmod -Rf 777 /media/name
```